# Unwanted image in RSS feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have a mysterious image showing up in my RSS feed. It is the featured image for a post from over a year ago. I have inspected all of the feed php files, which are simply the unaltered Wordpress defaults, and can find nothing to indicate this image should be there. I cannot find anything in  any of theme theme files either. Here is an abbreviated snippet of the feed, appearing after the metadata and before the content:

```
<description><![CDATA[<a href="https://gypsyplate.com/grillades-and-grits/">
<img src="https://gypsyplate.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/grillades_square-150x150.jpg" /></a>
<img src="https://gypsyplate.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Classic-Marinara_600x600.jpg" />
```

I have installed a plugin to place the featured image in the feed, which is the image within the link. However, even prior to installing the plugin the second image always showed up in the feed items. The image is not anywhere in the source for the particular post itself. Any ideas?

Comment: A quick google search of "unwanted image wordpress" suggests to turn off all plugins and re-enable them one bye one to figure out if this is caused by a plugin. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the theme is hooking on the RSS feed or overloading it, try checking for it:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds